# CSS Scrolling bar assistance

Tags: html, css

How would I manage to change the length of the custom scroll bar that this code creates, I'm trying to make a compact blog sort of thing so please help :)

```
div.custom-scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 210px;
}

.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.custom-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color:#028eff;
}
```

Comment: To adjust the length, just change the height of `.custom-scroll`

Comment: Can you include an example of the HTML that these CSS defintions are to be applied to? That may make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: "<div class="place">
<div class="custom-scroll">
<div class="background">
<div class="transbox">
<p><font size="5" color="White" face="verdana">Hello World</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>"

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to change the `height` value in the custom-scroll div, that's the only value that looks relevant to your question.